# How to raise error when including a module that already has same-name methods

Tags: ruby

### Given:

```
module Foo
  def bar
    puts 'Foo Bar!'
  end
end

class Person
  def bar
    puts 'Person Bar!'
  end
end

class Person
  # I want this line to raise an error because Foo and Person has same-named methods that would break dependencies if ignored
  include Foo
end

Person.new.bar
# => Person Bar!
```

### Question:

- From the code above, I am looking for an alternative to `include` and `extend` that would do the same thing except that it will raise an error when included or extended methods are already defined.
- Is there something like `include!` or `extend!`?

### Usage:

- I am writing a small gem that would be adding methods to the `Object` class:

  ```
  class Object
    include MyGemName
  end
  ```

  , and I want to make sure first that there are no same-name methods defined yet on the `Object` class.

### Attempts:

```
class Person
  duplicate_methods = self.instance_methods(false) & Foo.instance_methods(false)
  raise "#{self} already has methods: #{duplicate_methods}" unless duplicate_methods.empty?
  include Foo
end
```

- above works, but because this is my first gem and that I feel that "naming" is a "usual" programming problem, that perhaps there is just some "simpler" way of doing this.

**Note:**

- It is a requirement for me to override the `Object` class, because I want to skip passing `self` as an argument to the said methods.
- I might be missing just simple thing here, but my search over the internet yields me no helpful solution. Perhaps then, I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Being able to override same-named methods in subclasses is a key feature of inheritance in Ruby, so there is no built-in way to prevent it. (`include` simply makes the module the superclass of the class, so this is just class-inheritance, too.) What should happen if I `include` the module *first* and *then* add a same-named method to the class? What should happen if I `include` 2 modules with same-named methods? How can I override a mixed in method?

Comment: "What should happen if I include the module first and then add a same-named method to the class?" If another method was later added to the class which then overrides my method (then I think whoever implement that code should take responsibility, that is he/she makes sure that the method is not yet there, or that he/she knows what to do when there is already a method; which is just like me myself asking this question). This normally shouldn't be a problem because overriding methods is constrained to a namespace module or application, however I am overriding a generic `Object`  so...

Comment: ... I need to make sure it's safe. Or... maybe this was not a really good idea of mine, I guess?

Comment: How are you enforcing load order of the files? Ruby has open classes, you can add anything to a class at anytime. `include`ing the module first and later adding a same-named method is *exactly the same thing* as adding a same-named method first and `include`ing later … it just depends on which file happens to get loaded first.

Comment: yes the order matters. I am loading all my lib files at the very end after every gem dependency has already been loaded. So this means then that I'm sure that it won't be overriden later then right? or at least if someone overrides it later then he's using my gem incorrectly or that he knows what he's doing, or that I could provide some proper way of overriding the methods in my git readme. Although, I havent seen something like this in ruby or gems that checks for "safetiness", so maybe it's best for me to not check this after all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *really* want this behaviour, you could consider the following:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    overrides = instance_methods.select { |method| base.instance_method(method).owner != self }
    raise "#{self.name} overrides #{overrides.join(', ')}" if overrides.any?
  end
end
```

Running your code would get the following results:

> in `included': Foo overrides bar (RuntimeError)

Comment: this is interesting! thanks! I'll try this when I get back to the office :)

Comment: Just found out though that this only works if `def bar` is not defined on `Foo`, but is defined on `Person`. But it doesn't work when `def bar` is defined on `Foo`, but is not defined on `Person`

Comment: Right, let me think of a way around that one :)

Comment: No worries! Take your time! :) I'll see what I can do as well.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario okay, think i've found it ;-)